# C# UniqueAttribute validation check DB and ignore old value

Tags: c#

I create my own `UniqueAttribute` validation which check data in DB.

Problem is how to ignore own row.

So example:

> Current email address: test@test.com Current address: Address1

now I change

> Current address: Address2 Current email address: test@test.com ->
>   stays the same

I get message that this email already exist. How to remember old value?

Code:

```
#region

using Agado.Jobs.Infrastructure.ExtensionMethods;
using Agado.Jobs.StudentService.Web.Infrastructure.Utils;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;

#endregion

        namespace Agado.Jobs.StudentService.Web.Infrastructure.Validators
        {           

            [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
            public class UniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
            {
                public UniqueAttribute(Type dataContextType, Type entityType, string propertyName, string methodName)
                {
                    DataContextType = dataContextType;
                    EntityType = entityType;
                    PropertyName = propertyName;
                    MethodName = methodName;
                }

                public Type DataContextType { get; private set; }
                public Type EntityType { get; private set; }
                public string PropertyName { get; private set; }
                public string MethodName { get; private set; }

                protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
                {
                    if (value == null) return ValidationResult.Success;

                    var idValue = ValidationUtils.GetValue<int>(validationContext.ObjectInstance, "Id");
                    var repository = Jobs.Infrastructure.IoC.Resolve(DataContextType);

                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = EntityType.GetProperty(PropertyName);
                    if (propertyInfo == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("PropertyInfo with name '{0}' is NULL".FormatWith(PropertyName));
                    }

                    var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                    if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                    {
                        propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
                    }

                    var args = new[] { Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType) };
                    var data = repository.GetType().InvokeMember(MethodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, null, repository, args);

                    if (idValue != 0 && data != null)
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                    }
                    else if (idValue == 0 && data != null)
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new RequiredAttribute().IsValid(value) ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                    }

                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }

                public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
                    {
                        var genericMessageWithPlaceHolder = (string)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("PropertyUniqueDefaultError");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(genericMessageWithPlaceHolder))
                        {
                            ErrorMessage = genericMessageWithPlaceHolder;
                        }
                    }
                    return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString, name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Use:

```
[Unique(typeof(ICustomerRepository), typeof(customers), "Email", "GetByEmail")]
        [Display(Name = Translations.Global.EMAIL)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: What if you will add something like `if (idValue != 0 && data != null && data.Id != idValue)`? If your `data` is of type `object` then extract `id` property using reflection.

Comment: "IdValue" can be value of another template and not customers table. For example I am now in "students" table, I am using same formModel and id is from this table not from customers

Comment: Also I don't know why you are passing the name of the property to `UniquesAttribute` contructor. This information can be deduced from `ValidationContext` object passed to `IsValid`.

Comment: You are right but is not relevant for my problem

Comment: *"IdValue" can be value of another template and not customers table. For example I am now in "students" table, I am using same formModel and id is from this table not from customers* - If so, then you might consider providing additional parameter of the name of identity property to extract from data and compare to `IdValue`. For example `studentId`, `customerId`.

Comment: you mean in form model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106617/discussion-between-ivan-gritsenko-and-senzacionale).